# when parameter is empty set own value php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have this query, which is inserting data to my table:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO reservations 
     (name, start, end,room_id, status, paid, customer, name_ship, equipment, port,
         ETA, ETD, service_id, service_classification, job, active) 
VALUES (:name, :start, :end, :room,  :status, 0, :customer, :name_ship, :equipment, :port, 
        :ETA, :ETD, :service_id, :service_classification, :job, 1)");
 $stmt->bindParam(':start', $_POST['start']);
 $stmt->bindParam(':end', $_POST['end']);
 $stmt->bindParam(':name', $_POST['name']);
 $stmt->bindParam(':room', $_POST['room']);
 $stmt->bindParam(':status', $_POST['status']);
 $stmt->bindParam(':customer', $_POST['customer']);
 $stmt->bindParam(':name_ship', $_POST['name_ship']);
 $stmt->bindParam(':equipment', $_POST['equipment']);
 $stmt->bindParam(':port', $_POST['port']);
 $stmt->bindParam(':ETA', $_POST['ETA']);
 $stmt->bindParam(':ETD', $_POST['ETD']);
 $stmt->bindParam(':service_id', $_POST['service_id']);
 $stmt->bindParam(':service_classification', $_POST['service_classification']);
 $stmt->bindParam(':job', $_POST['job']);
 $stmt->execute();

class Result {}

 $response = new Result();
 $response->result = 'OK';
 $response->message = 'Created with id: '.$db->lastInsertId();
 $response->id = $db->lastInsertId();

 header('Content-Type: application/json');
 echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

And I would like to chceck if :port has some value and if not, set static value. 
So probably like this should go before execute
`if (:port =="") {port='9999';} else {:port}  or if(empty(:port){}else{}` Am I right? 
Thanks

Comment: @Jens if the insert statement provides explicit value, then the database level default value will be overwritten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the ternary operator `?:`:

$stmt->bindParam(':port', empty($_POST['port']) ? '9999' : $_POST['port']);

`empty()` is true if either 'port' element is not set in `$_POST` or if it is set but false or 0 or an empty string.

Comment: And if I would like to make comparsion  if :port value is bigger than 1000 save into shipyard else to port                                                                  (':port', ($_POST['port'])>1000 ? $_POST['port']) : $_POST['shipyard']);  would it be correct?

Comment: `w = x ? y : z` is kind of a shortcut of `if (x) { w=y; } else { w=z; }`, so you can use every boolean value for z.

Comment: Thank you..Im going to use it ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is the value you're looking to check:

```
$_POST['port']
```

You can use the conditional operator to have it evaluate to the desired value in-line.  Something as simple as this may be what you want:

```
isset($_POST['port']) ? $_POST['port'] : '9999'
```

Or you can add more conditions depending on the extent of what you need to check.  For example:

```
(isset($_POST['port']) && !empty($_POST['port'])) ? $_POST['port'] : '9999'
```

But the overall structure is the same.  Basically:

```
condition ? value_if_true : value_if_false
```

The entire statement evaluates to the resulting value so it can be used in-line.